# Unrecognized selector when populating an NSManagedObject with MagicalRecord

Tags: objective-c, ios7, magicalrecord

I have an iPad app that I am porting from Windows C#.  I created the entity and attributes (parital listing in image):

[image]

This is how I defined the attributes in the app:

[image: .h file]

[image: .m file]

This is the code to initialize MagicalRecord (v2.3) in AppDelegate.m file:

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"bim.sqlite"];      
defaultContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
```

I have this code in the DetailViewController.m file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Books.h"

@class Books;

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
}
```

This is the code causing the error:

```
- (IBAction)aAddRecordToCoreData:(UIButton *)sender {

Books *bks = [Books MR_createEntity];

bks.aAuthor = oAuthor.text;
bks.aBinding = oBinding.text;
bks.aBookDescription = oDescription.text;
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
-[Books setAAuthor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

As far as I can tell, this is the same code I have used in another iPad app which is working correctly in the App Store.  I doubt it has anything to do with MagicalRecord, but one never knows.  What am I missing? or doing wrong?

Comment: "books.h" vs "Books.h" ?

Comment: Does it make any difference what the file is named, as long as it is found?

Comment: The name of the include file could be "videogames.h" -- it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: I suspect that Objective-C's name mangling is at fault.  Try `bookPtr.aAuthor = whatever;`.  If not that then likely the auto-synthesize stuff is confused and you need to explicitly code @synthesize.

Comment: (Neither of these possibilities is "normal", but you likely have introduced some "odd" features from C#.)

Comment: UPDATED question...(missing code that caused the exception)

Comment: Uh, hold it -- @dynamic??  No, I don't think so.  You never need to use @dynamic, except when you're doing something strange.

Comment: @HotLicks: When I ask XCode to create the .h/.m from my DataModel, it's in `@dynamic` in my .m. Anyway, is it normal that in the model, it's `author` and in the .h/.m it's `aAuthor`?

Comment: @Larme:  that's it!  please re-write your comment as the answer so I can award points... and thank you so much... sometimes I can't see the tree because of the forest!  :D

Comment: Remove @dynamic.  What that means is "don't generate setters and getters."

Comment: @HotLicks: `@dynamic` is **correct** and required for all *Core Data attributes*, because the setters/getters are created dynamically at runtime.